# Is this ISS artwork old but accurate? Was there a radiator that looked like this once?

Tags: iss, history, space-art

Along with today's NPR.org news article [NASA Needs Backup Plan To Maintain U.S. Presence At Space Station, Watchdog Says](https://www.npr.org/2018/07/12/628302371/nasa-needs-backup-plan-to-maintain-u-s-presence-at-space-station-watchdog-says) there is a big of ISS artwork of the ISS. The caption says:

> International Space Station (ISS), computer artwork. Sciepro/Getty Images/Science Photo Library RF

Is this a fairly old but accurately represented configuration for the ISS at one point? I see a radiator deployed on a scaffolding tower extending a significant distance away from the rest of the structure. Is this this an accurate representation of a radiator configuration at one point as well? Or is this an artists concept before the ISS design was even complete?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not even a good image of the proposed element. See the image at the wikipedia link in Tristan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the [Science Power Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Power_Platform) (warning, linked article is incomplete and contains some inaccuracies), a long-canceled element of the Russian segment of the ISS.